# Which settings do I change so I can view the images in my react build after uploading it to my host?

Tags: reactjs

I built my react application using

```
npm build run
```

In the build folder, I have a static folder, asset-manifest, favicon, index, manifest, and service worker files.

Within the static folder I have my js, css, and media folders.
Within my media is where I keep all of my images.

My goal is to upload this build on to my website.

my website is https://pnatchev.com/

I want to place the build within https://pnatchev.com/burgerbuilder/

So far I have made everything work but my **image at the top left of my burger builder page** is not appearing.

I feel like I am missing something simple for the pathways, but I am not sure what I should change because I have tried different sections of these files and no change is happening. If anyone has run into this problem please give me some advice so I can make my image appear.

By the way, I use Siteground as my host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the README that create-react-app put in your folder](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/4879425e69a0e12758c7adff47eb8df5a1a30db9/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths):

> By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is
>   hosted at the server root.
>  To override this, specify the
>   `homepage` in your `package.json`, for example:
>
> ```
>   "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
> ```
>
> This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in
>   the generated HTML file.

In your case, it should be `https://pnatchev.com/burgerbuilder`, given where you uploaded the build directory to.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Now I can continue to become better at react :).